# Jittery jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

HTML

```
<div class="phone">
  <a href="#" >
    <img src="/assets/phonenew.png" alt="" height="90px" width="90px" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="phone-number">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="/assets/phonenumber.png" class="phone-full" height="45px" />
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.phone {
 position: absolute;
 top: 200px;
 left: 915px;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 100;
}

.phone-number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 225px;
  left: 908px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 28px;
  color: rgb(68, 69, 67);
}
```

This is the jQuery I'm using to make my phone icon (phonenew.png) slide left on mouseenter exposing .phone-number, then rolls back right on mouseleave, hiding .phone-number. This animation is very jittery. I think I am missing a step like queueing or something..

```
    $.fn.animateRotate = function(angle,prevAngle, duration, easing, complete) {
  var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
  var step = args.step;
  return this.each(function(i, e) {
      args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
      args.step = function(now) {
          $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
          if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
      };

      $({deg: prevAngle}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
  });
 };
var angle = 0;
var prevAngle = 0;

$(".phone").mouseenter(function(e) {
  prevAngle = angle
  angle -= 100;
  $(this).animateRotate(angle, prevAngle, 250);
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).animate({
    left: "800px",
    opacity: 1
  }, {
    duration: 300,
    queue: false
  });
  $(".phone-number").fadeIn(1000);
  // $(".phone-number").show("slide", 400);
});
$(".phone").mouseleave(function(e) {
prevAngle = angle
angle += 100;
$(this).animateRotate(angle, prevAngle, 350);
e.preventDefault();
$(this).animate({
  left: "905px",
  opacity: 1
  }, {
    duration: 300,
    queue: false
  });
  $(".phone-number").hide("slide", "easeInQuart", 300);
});
```

Comment: What browser?  What Operating System?  Same results on all?  Try to record the animation in Chrome Dev Tools. You can watch frame rates and see what operations are delayed.  Anything slower then 30 frames/second = jitter. Oh and Safari isn't your friend.

Comment: Chrome, OS Mavericks, I haven't used Chrome Dev Tools yet..

Comment: Jump on in, the water's fine!  And here's [your how to link...](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline)

Comment: Jittery may be the wrong word.. The animation reloads too quickly and causes a studder. This is because the area that is being hovered is animating away from the pointer, then when the pointer is moved the animation jumps to home position and reloads...no good..

Comment: So you can still load up the Chrome Dev Tools and see exactly where that jump is occurring.  You're going to start to record... play with the site a few times then stop the recording and then replay it (and inspect the results...)  Do you have a JS fiddle set up anywhere so we can see what you see dynamically? (or a public facing web page?)

Answer (score 0):

So, yeah.  I recommend strongly that its time to start using Chrome Browser and its Dev Tools.  I've created (a Sloppy) JSFiddle from your code extract.  Its not perfect, I had to change a few things.  Note: I'm using jQuery 2.2.3   What version are you using?

Its here:  https://jsfiddle.net/ubv51rdk/9/

When I start the animation I immediately see a repeating error:

`Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function`

According to https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.speed/, the easing argument defaults to "swing" but you're just using the word "easing"  You've got to place something else there... there are a ton of choices.  Check out https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

And I will suggest.. when you are coding you will ALWAYS be stretching to learn and try new things.  Just be careful of stretching too much.. You should strive to always understand what each and every line of code in your program does.  (A rule lots of us break...)  For somebody who has NEVER used Chrome DevTools to understand how JavaScript works behind the scenes, this program as written is a mighty big stretch.  Almost too much. the `animateRotate` function with its convoluted `args` object does not make this easy to understand.    The fact that the inputs to the function call aren't being used (both `easing` and `complete`) and the totally confusing issue surrounding `args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);` and the following `step` function are having me pull my hair out.

Without seeing the original code in its original form, this is more than frustrating.  Do you have a reference?  Is this from a Wheel of Fortune example?

So, I'm trying to step thru the code, and apparently JS fiddle has changed its formats a whole lot. I don't see how its possible to place a watch on variables and step thru the code in JS fiddle.  Too much overhead.  I think that would have to be done in a simple website either on local host or hosted on the web somewhere.  If you do that, and step thru the code, you will want to watch the `args` object.  Its not clear to me on how the `complete` thing works or why my `swing` input still is generating errors.

I'm ready to delete my answer, wish you the best of luck and move on.

Comment: Just made my first JSFiddle, thanks..  https://jsfiddle.net/Emaren/0nynL142/    Can't get my icon (hosted on imgur) through to JSFiddle though...

Comment: Yeah, I just grabbed some extraneous images off the web.  In fact have you seen any [number of place holder images?](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-top-8-placeholder-services-for-web-designers--net-19485) Anything will work...And hey,  you are welcome to update the fiddle I started... not a big deal.